# return new array with values greater than or equal to "threshold"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

My function is supposed to create an new array with values the are greater than or equal to the threshold. It will take an array as an input.

```
int * filterThreshold(const int *arr, int size, int threshold, int *resultSize)
{
  int newSize = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)// inc for ever valid int in array
  {
    if(arr[i] >= threshold)
    {
      newSize =+ 1;
    }
  }
  int *returnArr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * newSize);// create new array based on how many valid values
  int x = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)// set values in returnArr
  {
    if(arr[i] >= threshold)
    {
      returnArr[x] = arr[i];
      x++;
    }
  }
  *resultSize = newSize;// point cast size back
  free(returnArr);//free memory allocation
  return returnArr;// return the new array
}
```

My compiler keeps saying "malloc() corrupted top size"??? I free the unnecessary memory that gets allocated.

Comment: `free(returnArr);` makes the subsequent line, `return returnArr;` , nonsense. You're literally intentionally returning a dangling pointer, set to dangle just one line beforehand. Just `return returnArr;` and let the *caller* do the `free` once done with the resulting sequence.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that wasn't the problem. My compiler didn't like how I was incrementing "newSize". I used "newSize++" and it worked. Thanks for the tip though, I didn't know it automatically free'd the memory.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, oh. Yea makes sense, if it did it the value at the memory address could be overwritten by another process. Had a stupid moment...